# Map a list to a value with non commutative function in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, commutativity

Hello I have a function foo (Int -> Int -> Int) in haskell and I want to map each element of a list [1..y] to a value x which I would usually do like this:

```
map (foo x) [1..y]
```

the problem is my function is not commutative so what I actually want to do is something like this (careful incorrect syntax ahead):

```
map (foo [1..y]) x
```

So basically I want to pass my function each element of a list and map each element to x but the values [1..y] need to be on the left side of the function. Note that **foo** takes two Ints as arguments. I am sure haskell has some trick in its repository for this, can you help me out :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
λ> map (flip (-) 3) [1..10]
[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

[`flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) takes a function of type `a -> b -> c` and two arguments `b` and `a` (in that order) and applies the function to the arguments in flipped order.

Another way that comes to mind is used `zip` and an infinite list of `x` (3 in this example) to create pairs of arguments that you want you function applied to.

Answer (score 0):

The function "flip" out of the prelude did the trick for me :)

```
map (flip foo x) [1..y]
```

Comment: You can also work with operator sectioning, like ``map (`foo` x) [1 .. y]``